# Is it possible to list all searches with at least one result that were made on a site?

Tags: search

I want to submit a XML sitemap to Google with frontend searches, in order to boost the SEO for a site.

This is the approach I would take. But then, I might be very naive and there's other techniques for boosting the SEO with predefined searches?!

Comment: I assume you mean all front-end searches on a site and not necessarily Control Panel searches?

Comment: that's right. Updated question.

Comment: Thought I had a easy solution, but thinking though it, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe you could piece it together with a plugin that listened to https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onBuildElementsQuery, checked if the "search" criteria was set, grab the search query and log it?